# What is this adm command in linux?

Tags: linux

I am trying to write a Java program that calls linux system commands.
I came across it as this `adm -i -u username`

The is no man page, and which returns `/usr/bin/adm`. I can't find anything online.

Comment: Can you please tell the source where you found this command ?

Comment: It was given to me. The person who used it just used it as told.

Comment: may be it is group...see this:http://serverfault.com/questions/485473/what-is-the-canonical-use-for-the-sys-and-adm-groups

Comment: adm: Group adm is used for system monitoring tasks. Members of this group can read many log files in /var/log, and can use xconsole. Historically, /var/log was /usr/adm (and later /var/adm), thus the name of the group. source:http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1318346